# How would I redirect index.php to index.php?route=home, and rewrite it to /home?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm just starting out with .htaccess `mod_rewrite` and I've found myself stumped:

I'm building an application (using a MVC pattern,) that loads the views into `index.php` based on the query string; eg. `domain.com/index.php?route=home` will load the home page.

What this means however, is that `domain.com/index.php` with no query string loads nothing... or more to the point, `domain.com` loads nothing.

. . .

What I would like, is for `domain.com` (and `domain.com/index.php`)

to redirect to `domain.com/index.php?route=home`,

and then have `domain.com/index.php?route=home` rewritten as `domain.com/home`.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a good place to learn how to effectively use `.htaccess`

[Tips and Tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

so this link:

```
http://www.example.com/home
```

will redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=home
```

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

using the condition will make sure your css and javascript doesnt break

Edit: due to comment By Shango, i changed `/^(.*)/` to `^(.*)`

Comment: I tried `RewriteEngine On` and then `RewriteRule /^(.*)/ index.php?route=$1 [L]` but it says "The requested URL /home was not found on this server" when I typed in `http://domain.com/home`. I also need to add a query string by default, not just `domain.com/home` redirecting.

Comment: for testing change the `[L]` to `[R,L]` and tell me what is the url on the address bar

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]  this should append the query string also

Comment: Using `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]` (I noticed there is no forward slash in the beginning) worked... however the site couldn't load my CSS—something about the redirect must have broken my file paths.

Comment: What's weird is that when I go to `index.php?route=home` directly now, the file paths are still broken.

Comment: @Ibu - Removing the `/`'s from `/^(.*)/` and adding `QSA` makes your above code work flawlessly. I can handle the `index.php` to `index.php?route=home` in my application, and your .htaccess code handles the `index.php?route=home` to `home`.  Thanks.

Comment: *Note: Both solutions worked online, but only this solution worked locally (on WAMP 2.1d.) Maybe it's just my server configuration, but I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: sorry didn't notice the first answer was updated, perhaps first answer update should work better. just the QSA

Comment: Works great. Your additions were key to getting this working.